# Cannot start JVM in Eclipse External Tools with Flight Recording Args

Tags: java, eclipse, external, jmc, jfr

I am invoking my java code via Eclipse External Tools as an ant target.

I want to monitor the JVM with JMC (Mission Control) and hence start up the Eclipse External Tools with arguments:

`"-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"`.

However, when I run it, the first error in the log file is:

`"Unknown argument: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"`

Also, when I run the flight recorder on this process, it complains:

`"Flight Recorder features are not enabled. To enable this you need to use a Java 7u4 or later JVM started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder."`

Looks like I am not setting the args in the correct place in eclipse.

Edit after the answer: If I invoke Java from commandline it looks fine, but when I invoke from eclipse external tools, that is the issue. Attached screenshot.[Eclipse External Tools invoked with JVM args for JMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn8CX.png)

Comment: What's the Java version you are using?

Comment: I am using Java 1.7.0_80.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running with a non HotSpot JVM, or one prior to JDK 7u4, perhaps mistakenly.

I copied your command line argument above and ran it on my machine with 1.7.0_60 with the following output:

```
 C:\JVMs\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -version
 java version "1.7.0_60"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b33)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

 C:\JVMs\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a flightrecording of your ant build, move the "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder" flags to the JRE tab, and place them without quotes in the VM Arguments field.

Comment: Now, this is the answer which works!! I gave this as VM arguments and everything works like smoothly. Thanks